# Chassidic Statement Supporting Misnagdim

Tags: sources-mekorot, chasidut-hasidism, chassidic-rebbe, misnaged

I heard from my Rabbi that there was a Chassidic rebbe (possibly Lubavitch) who said that if not for the Misnagdim the Chassidim would've gone off the derech/ not remained within orthodoxy. Does anyone know where this statement can be found?

Comment: I heard something similar from Rabbi Berel Wein (who is not Chassidic) using the analogy of two people pulling on a rope going down a road. The pulling to opposite sides keep them from falling off the sides.

Comment: It was attributed to the Tzemach Tzedek, 3d Chabad-Lubavitcher Rebbe. However, his exact words and where it is sourced, I do not know offhand. I just heard it repeated in Yeshivah with various versions. He was known as the peacemaker with misnagdim due to his relationship with R' Yitchak Volozhiner and his greatness in psak Halachah

Comment: seems unlikely to have come from a chassidic rebbe